# Rails has_many with accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, devise, has-many

I am having 2 models having has_many through relationships:
user model:

> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> has_many :agreements
>
> accepts_nested_attributes_for :agreements
>
> end

Agreement model

> class Agreement < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> belongs_to :user
>
> end

I am sending my agreements through seeds.rb file:

> Agreement.create(:agg_name => "Agreement1", :agg_template =>
>   "Agreement1 Template",:agg_type => "News")
>
> Agreement.create(:agg_name => "Agreement2", :agg_template =>
>   "Agreement2 Template")

Now my aim is to show agg_name **which has no agg_type (i.e. Agreement2)** with check box in the general devise **form** which has f.email, f.password and f.confirm_password

Please try to help me out.